# Не могу импортировать модуль с github

Tags: python, github

Мне нужно импортировать модуль, расположенный по ссылке : 
https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser

Я пробовал скачивать его следующими способами:
Используя pip install git + url
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используя pip install --upgrade url
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, что делать или даст другие способы импортирования?

Comment: вместо картинок, используйте текст, чтобы показать ваши команды и полученные ошибки. Это может помочь другим людям с похожей проблемой найти ответ (основная миссия SO). Если не знаете как скопировать текст из консоли, то задайте отдельный вопрос, специально об этом.

Comment: @jfs Хорошо, учту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае вокруг плюса не должно быть пробелов: `pip install git+url`.

В вашем случае команда выглядит так:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser
```

Чтобы сработало, должен быть установлен git.

Во втором случае url должен указывать на архив с исходниками, а не просто на репозиторий. Ключ `--upgrade`  для первоначальной установки не нужен. Команда будет выглядеть так:

```
pip install https://github.com/пользователь/имя_репозитория/archive/master.zip#egg=имя_репозитория
```

`master` - имя ветки, из которой будем брать исходники. Параметр `egg` необходим для того, чтобы пакет установился с именем репозитория, а не именем zip архива (`master`).

Команда для вашего случая:

```
pip install https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser/archive/master.zip#egg=pyStatParser
```

Оба способа рабочие. Минус первого способа - должен быть установлен git, для второго способа нужны только Python и pip.

Еще один способ (используется при разработке пакетов) - клонировать репозиторий, потом из него (из папки с файлом `setup.py`) запустить команду `pip install -e .` (точка обозначает текущую директорию), тогда пакет будет установлен в "editable mode", т.е. при изменении в исходниках эти изменения сразу можно будет проверить, просто проимпортировав модуль (pip создаст ссылки на директорию с исходниками, а не скопирует исходники куда-то к себе). Для обычной установки с копированием исходников нужно просто убрать ключ `-e`.

Comment: pip install url не работает, выдает следующую ошибку : Cannot unpack file C:\Users\14BA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-od29w_cp-unpack\pyStatParser.git (downloaded from C:\Users\14BA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2pkqowhq-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\14BA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2pkqowhq-build

Comment: @Philippe, вы внимательно прочитали мой ответ? К url нужно добавить `/archive/master.zip#egg=имя_репозитория`

Comment: @Philippe добавил команды для вашего случая в ответ.

Comment: Использовал "команду для моего случая", но теперь вылетел следующий Exception socket.timeout: The read operation timed out и потом ещё один : ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='codeload.github.com', port=443): Read timed out.

Comment: @Philippe, перевожу: превышено время ожидания запроса. У вас видимо что-то с интернетом. У меня по обеим командам устанавливается.

Comment: @insolor: и без `#egg=имя-пакета`  части `pip install https://.../master.zip` работает. `#egg` часть для `-e` опции требуется.

Comment: @jfs, сейчас попробовал без `#egg` и из локального репозитория ставить, и из архива с github - вроде бы все нормально ставится. Уже не вспомню, зачем мне эта опция понадобилась.